# How to hyperlink datalist elements in php?

Tags: php

I am new in php, and trying to use datalist on my project. But I don't know how to use hyperlink in option values used in a datalist.

Here is the code:

```
     <input type="text" list="gt"  />
<datalist name="dt" id="gt" >
     <?php
     while($result33=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select33))
     {
     ?>
     <option value="artistdetail.php?id=<?php echo $result33['ID']; ?>"> <?php echo  $result33['name']; ?> </option>

      <?php
      }
      ?>
      </datalist>
```

Comment: Can you explain, what is the use?

Comment: What would the result even look like?

Comment: I want to redirect on other page by selecting the option value. But i can't....

Comment: If your intention is just to redirect the user when a option is selected, then you just have to add a anchor within your option tags. like this ., `<option value="something"><a href="target.php" /> </option>`.

Comment: I think you may have to use Javascript to do this.

Comment: do u have  any working example?

Comment: nobody knows how to sort out this problem??????....